# Como faço para estilizar componentes filhos através dos componentes pais?

Tags: react-native, style

Estou aprendendo React native, e estou com uma dúvida relacionada à estilizar componentes filhos de forma mais produtiva, pois até o momento, tenho que criar um estilo e inseri-lo em cada componente que desejo estilizar.

A minha dúvida é: como criar somente um estilo, e através dele estilizar os componentes filhos sem precisar inserir o estilo no componente filho?

Por exemplo:

```
<View style={ styles.pai }>
  <Text>Texto 1</Text>
  <Text>Texto 2</Text>
  <Text>Texto 3</Text>
</View>
```

Quero que todos os componentes Text filhos do componente View com o estilo `style={ styles.pai }` tenham a cor vermelha.

No CSS isso seria feito usando herança, dessa forma:

```
.pai Text{
  color: red;
 }
```

Como fazer isso em React native deixando o código mais limpo?

Comment: Você pode tentar usar o styled-component ... onde vc usar o css puro pra editar algumas coisas. Da uma olhada no site deles: https://www.styled-components.com/